# How to write xpath for span element which generate messages dynamically?

Tags: xpath, html, selenium-ide

In the app I used, resolutions will be there to which a user can commit.
I committed to a resolution, which gives a message:

> You have committed successfully to this resolution'. Here is the html code for that message.

HTML for that messages is:

```
<div id="sliding_info_container" class="hidden" style="display: none;">
<span id="sliding_info" class="success">You have committed successfully to this resolution</span>
```

Now if I uncommit that resolution, app gives another message:

> Resolution uncommitted successfully

Here is the HTML code for that message:

```
<div id="sliding_info_container" class="hidden" style="display: block;">
<span id="sliding_info" class="success">Resolution uncommitted successfully</span>
```

My script for first action contains `xpath=//div/span[@class="success"], value=You have committed successfuly to this resolution`.
When I run this command selenium gives an error:  **Actual value 'Resolution uncommitted successfully' did not match 'You have committed successfully to this resolution'**

What I have given in the script is the right value, and that is the message app is displaying. Why selenium is giving out error for a valid command?

Comment: Please help me, I am a beginner in Selenium

Comment: This is not an XPath error. Given your `<span/>` is directly inside a `<div/>` tag, you do not need to change your XPath expression, it is totally fine. The problem is somewhere else. Please post a reasonable amount of example input, including the possible source of the wrong output.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for the prompt response Jens Erat.

Comment: You have to post much more information on your problem if you want help: What are you trying to do? What's the relevant code? What's the relevant input? Nobody _is able_ to help you with the information available. Read [ask]. And if you add more information, please edit your question, don't squeeze it into comments.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the suggestion made, and here i edited my question. I hope you can get the point now. Please go through my question now.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
//span[text()='You have committed successfully to this resolution']
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
//div/span[@class="success"]/text()
```

Comment: :( Again same error:  Actual value 'Resolution uncommitted successfully' did not match 'You have committed successfully to this resolution' even after using the xpath: //div/span[@class="success"]/text()